# OpenVPN and port forwarding

Tags: linux, openvpn, port-forwarding

I have an issue with my Linux-based server regarding VPN and port forwarding. I am also a beginner is this area, so forgive me for any mistake.

First, let me describe you the infrastructure. I have a Linux VPS server (**S1**) with openvpn properly configured, and a machine with Linux (**C1**) also with openvpn properly configured. THe are connected using port number **1194**. This is basically the scheme:

```
    S1
    [ip: X.X.X.221]
    [tun0 ip: 10.8.0.1]

    C1
    [ip: Y.Y.Y.19]
    [tun0 ip: 10.8.0.6]
```

When I say it is all properly configured is because I can successfully ping 10.8.0.1 from **C1**.

Now, it comes the problem...
I have a service **P1** running on port **1800** in **S1**, and a client for that service in **C1**. I can successfully give the IP address **X.X.X.221:1800** to the client in **C1**, but I want the client to acess **P1** via VPN connection. Is that a way to do it?

At first I thought this was simply a port forwarding problem, and all I needed to do was to forward every request from port **1194** to port **1800**, and I found this command to do it (btw, *venet0* is my interface):

```
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i venet0 -p udp --dport 1194 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1800
```

But this won't work.

Any help? Thanks :)

---

**EDIT1:**

Result of issuing `netstat -rn` and `10.8.0.6` in **S1**:

```
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
    10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
    10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tun0
    0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U         0 0          0 venet0

    traceroute to 10.8.0.6 (10.8.0.6), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
     1  10.8.0.6 (10.8.0.6)  116.769 ms  119.000 ms  120.618 ms
```

Result of issuing `netstat -rn` and `traceroute 10.8.0.1` in **C1**:

```
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
    0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
    10.8.0.1        10.8.0.5        255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 tun0
    10.8.0.5        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
    192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0

    traceroute to 10.8.0.1 (10.8.0.1), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
     1  10.8.0.1 (10.8.0.1)  83.825 ms  83.639 ms  86.877 ms
```

**EDIT 2:**

Configuration file for **S1** (I believe what starts with a **;** is not considered):

```
    ;local a.b.c.d
    port 1194
    proto udp
    dev tun
    ;dev-node MyTap
    ca ca.crt
    cert server.crt
    key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
    dh dh2048.pem
    server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
    ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
    ;server-bridge 10.8.0.4 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.50 10.8.0.100
    ;push "route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0"
    ;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"
    ;client-config-dir ccd
    ;route 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
    ;client-config-dir ccd
    ;route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.252
    ;learn-address ./script
    push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
    push "dhcp-option WINS 8.8.4.4"
    ;client-to-client
    ;duplicate-cn
    keepalive 10 120
    ;tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
    ;cipher BF-CBC        # Blowfish (default)
    ;cipher AES-128-CBC   # AES
    ;cipher DES-EDE3-CBC  # Triple-DES
    comp-lzo
    ;max-clients 300
    user root
    group root
    persist-key
    persist-tun
    status openvpn-status.log
    ;log         openvpn.log
    ;log-append  openvpn.log
    verb 3
    ;mute 20
```

Configuration file for **C1**

```
    client
    remote 176.9.192.221 1194
    ca ca.crt
    cert client.crt
    key client.key
    cipher BF-CBC
    comp-lzo
    dev tun
    proto udp
    nobind
    persist-key
    persist-tun
    user root
    group root
```

Comment: `ping` is deceptive sometimes.  Use `tracert` or `traceroute`. You may need to print/review your entire IPTables or routing table as well.  If you set up a VPN, it's generally for a whole subnet or a distinct system, not port specific.  You can identify the port you use for the VPN, but that's also going to be the port all future communication uses (including other ports), because all data will now traverse through that port (including port 1800).  What's most likely happening is your routing table doesn't know the proper path to take.

Comment: So... if I have a VPN, how can I access the services in the network where the VPN is connected? Example: If I have a printer connected to **S1**, how do I access it via VPN?

Comment: The same way you would locally (on the S1's network), so long as you have the proper routes in place.  That's how VPN works; (simplified) it makes two networks communicate as if they were on the same network.

Comment: Well, then I guess that is my problem... How to have proper routes.

Comment: Dump your static routes with `netstat -rn` then paste the results in your question for both systems.  Also do a `tracert` or `traceroute` from both systems and post those up as well.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but what kind of traceroute do you need me to do? Can you show me the command? thanks!

Comment: From S1 to C1 and from C1 to S1; So, from S1: `traceroute 10.8.0.6` and from C1: `traceroute 10.8.0.1`.  If you set up your VPN properly, the traceroutes will show at the least: the local address, the VPN interface, * * *, the other VPN interface, the destination address

Comment: Ok done :) sorry for my ignorance, newbie here...

Comment: Can you confirm S1 and C1 are on different physical subnets?  It would also help if your tunnels were on different logical subnets as well; having them on the same subnets can create a routing loop, which is what you're probably seeing.  For S1, your routing table says everything on subnet `10.8.0.0` goes through the tunnel `10.8.0.2`, which is what you want.  For C1, you only have static routes for `10.8.0.1` and `10.8.0.5`, which points to itself; it doesn't know how to get to `10.8.0.2`.  My recommendation is to put the systems on different subnets first, then recheck your static routes.

Comment: **S1** and **C1** are on different physical subnets. The first is a VPS in Germany, the second is in my house. I don't see how can they be in the same subnet...
I followed this tutorial: [link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/09/openvpn-setup/) to configure the VPN in both client and server. What is missing? Does the problem that you just mentioned affect the solution I want to implement?

Comment: The static routes on C1 for `10.8.0.1` and `10.8.0.5` don't make any sense.  I'm surprised you were able to get a traceroute response.  Do you have your OpenVPN set up as site-to-site or client-server?

Comment: I am gonna Edit my question to include the configurations for server and client.

Comment: If S1 is the server and C1 is the client, then your static routes for C1 are screwed up.  It says that `10.8.0.1` is pointing to `10.8.0.5`, but `10.8.0.5` isn't anywhere in  your question.  If C1 is supposed to be `10.8.0.6`, then `10.8.0.1` should be pointing to `10.8.0.6`.

Comment: Ok, then... how to solve it? Does solving that also solves my original problem?

Comment: You could manually remove the existing static routes on C1 for `10.8.0.1` and `10.8.0.5`; example: `route del -net 10.8.0.1 gw 10.8.0.5 netmask 255.255.255.255 dev tun0`, then add a new route on C1 using `route add -net 10.8.0.1 gw 10.8.0.6 netmask 255.255.255.255 dev tun0` and see if that works.  Remember to keep track of your old routes, in case you need to re-add them.

Comment: Also, make sure your application P1 on S1 is able to utilize both eth0 and tun0 as it's network device.  Some Linux applications are network device specific (like SSH).

Comment: Well, I followed your instructions to fix the routes, and they appear to be correct now! However, my service **P1** does not work as I intend it to.
Note: the only thing I can change in **P1** configurations is the listening port.
How can I make a client **C1** use **P1** through the VPN, given that the only thing I can provide to **C1** is an IP and a port?

Comment: Congrats! for the 2nd part of issue, you need to do 1 of 2 things; 1) find a way to bind the P1 service on S1 to `tun0` instead of `dev0` or 2) configure your IPtables to forward your P1 traffic from `tun0` to `dev0` on S1.  There is a 3rd option you can try, but I'm not sure if it will work properly (it depends on how the internal networks are configured on both sides); this option is to build static routes from C1 to S1 and vice versa.  You have the static routes built for the VPN already, but you'll need to build it for the dev0 IPs to route through your VPN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could manually remove the existing static routes on C1 for `10.8.0.1` and `10.8.0.5`; example:

```
route del -net 10.8.0.1 gw 10.8.0.5 netmask 255.255.255.255 dev tun0
```

Then add a new route on C1 using:

```
route add -net 10.8.0.1 gw 10.8.0.6 netmask 255.255.255.255 dev tun0
```

See if that works. Remember to keep track of your old routes, in case you need to re-add them.  This should fix your VPN routing issue.

Your other issue is that your VPN network can't talk to the network where the OpenVPN's server's NIC sits on.  You can fix this by adding a new static route on each side for those networks.

On C1:

```
route add -net X.X.X.221 gw 10.8.0.6 netmask 255.255.255.255 dev tun0
```

On S1:

```
route add -net Y.Y.Y.19 gw 10.8.0.6 netmask 255.255.255.255 dev tun0
```

Note: I wouldn't recommend this unless you can revert your changes; in case it doesn't work.

You can also try using the `push route` option in your OpenVPN config.  For example:

```
push "route  X.X.X.221 255.255.255.0"
```

Lastly, if none of that works, you can try adding something in your IPTABLES to forward the traffic from your VPN network (NAT) to your local network on S1.  Something like:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.8.0.6 -p tcp --dport 1800 -j DNAT --to-destination X.X.X.221:1800
```

Comment: Thanks you, it worked perfectly! :D
(sorry for the delay, I was away for a few days...)

Answer (score 0):

So your service S1 must be listening on the VPN IP, 10.8.0.1, and your client C1 need to connect to 10.8.0.1:1800 ... as long as your VPN if fully working.

Comment: I connected the client *C1* to 10.8.0.1:1800, but it was not enough to make it work... How can I make **C1** use **P1** through the VPN, given that the only thing I can provide to **C1** is an IP and a port?

Comment: I mixed up a bit, sorry ... You connect your VPN (you said it works) and then the server application listen on 10.8.0.1:1800 and then the client software connects on 10.8.0.1:1800 ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your S1 service config not listening tun interface. There is no problem with routing. What is your service ? Can you show config of it ? 
Anyway -  try
`telnet 10.8.0.1 1800`       on S1
`telnet X.x.x.221 1800`       on S1.
If you will receive an answer in one of cases - search problem in service config file.